# How to get page number?

Tags: c#, interop

I have this code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
object nullobj = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
object file = openFileDialog1.FileName;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = app.Documents.Open(
  ref file, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
  ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
  ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
  ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
  ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);
doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();
doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();
IDataObject data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
string text = data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();
textBox2.Text = text;
doc.Close(ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);
app.Quit(ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);
```

But it does not return a page number.  How can I get the page number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this example:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/amrish_deep/WordAutomation05102007223934PM/WordAutomation.aspx

Specifically, look at `Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldPage` and `Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldNumPages`.

Comment: This would be a better answer if it included the essential parts of the answer here, and provided the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 6):

I'd say this is a better solution

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
object nullobj = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
object file = openFileDialog1.FileName;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = app.Documents.Open(
  ref file, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
  ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
  ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
  ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
  ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);
doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();
doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();
IDataObject data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();

// get number of pages
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdStatistic stat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdStatistic.wdStatisticPages;
int pages = doc.ComputeStatistics(stat, Type.Missing);

string text = data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();
textBox2.Text = text;
doc.Close(ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);
app.Quit(ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the ComputeStatistics function would give me a higher number than the actual number of pages so that didn't work for me.

I used range.get_Information()

```
var range = doc.Range().GoTo(WdGoToItem.wdGoToPage, WdGoToDirection.wdGoToLast);
var numPages = range.get_Information(WdInformation.wdActiveEndPageNumber);
```

The first line gets the range on the last page of the document.
The second line gets the page where the range is.