# C# converting Word VBA macro BuiltInDocumentProperties("Number of Pages") is null

Tags: c#, vba, ms-word, office-interop

I have a Word VBA macro that I am converting to C# using the `Office.Interop`.

The code works nicely and I was able to convert everything, but I got stuck with trying to read to number of pages from the `BuiltInDocumentProperties`.

No matter what `cast` I use, it still does not work and returns `null`.

Here is the converted code:

```cs
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using Microsoft.Office;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;

Word.Application oWord = new Word.Application();
Word.Document oTgtDoc = new Word.Document();

var PgNum = oTgtDoc.BuiltInDocumentProperties["Number of Pages"];

float intWidthCount = engColWidth;

while (true)
{
    oTgtDoc.Tables[1].Columns[1].SetWidth(intWidthCount, Word.WdRulerStyle.wdAdjustProportional);      

    intWidthCount += 5;
    oTgtDoc.Repaginate();
    oWord.Application.ScreenRefresh();

    if (oTgtDoc.BuiltInDocumentProperties["Number of Pages"] > PgNum && intWidthCount > engColWidth)
    {
        while (oTgtDoc.BuiltInDocumentProperties["Number of Pages"] > PgNum)
        {
            intWidthCount--;
            oTgtDoc.Tables[1].Columns[1].SetWidth(intWidthCount, Word.WdRulerStyle.wdAdjustProportional); 

            oTgtDoc.Repaginate();
            oWord.Application.ScreenRefresh();
        }
        break;
    } 
    else
    {
      PgNum = oTgtDoc.BuiltInDocumentProperties["Number of Pages"];
    }
```

I have looked at several other post and msdn and did not get to the right solution yet. For example this one: [Accessing document properties - Excel Workbook/CSV in VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20566655/accessing-document-properties-excel-workbook-csv-in-vb)

Or this one with the `Dictionary`, which would not work as I need to access it several times in the `while` loop: [Read BuiltInDocumentProperties/CustomDocumentProperties alway null with Word 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31826865/read-builtindocumentproperties-customdocumentproperties-alway-null-with-word-201)

Any suggestions how to access this `BuiltInDocumentProperties["Number of Pages"]` from my C# code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edited**: added example of using `var PgNum = oTgtDoc.BuiltInDocumentProperties(Word.WdBuiltInProperty.wdPropertyPages).Value.ToString();` before "Reflection" example

**edited 2**: to take account for OP's need to use `PgNum` as an int

you must use

```
 var PgNum = oTgtDoc.BuiltInDocumentProperties(Word.WdBuiltInProperty.wdPropertyPages).Value;
```

or

```
 int PgNum = oTgtDoc.BuiltInDocumentProperties(Word.WdBuiltInProperty.wdPropertyPages).Value;
```

and BTW

```
Word.Document oTgtDoc = new Word.Document();
```

won't return any new Word document (i.e. a 'real' new document in Word UI)  but just a new word document object in your class

should you actually want to have a new blank UI Word document than you'd use:

```
    object oMissing = Missing.Value;
    Word.Document oTgtDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
```

---

here's how I tested `var PgNum = oTgtDoc.BuiltInDocumentProperties(Word.WdBuiltInProperty.wdPropertyPages).Value.ToString();` with a console application

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {    
            RunWordExample();
        } 


        static void RunWordExample()
        {
            Word.Application oWord = new Word.Application(); //Create an instance of Microsoft Word

            //Create a new Document
            object oMissing = Missing.Value;
            Word.Document oTgtDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

            //make Word visible
            oWord.Visible = true;

            // get number of pages #1
            var PgNum = oTgtDoc.BuiltInDocumentProperties(Word.WdBuiltInProperty.wdPropertyPages).Value.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("doc {0} has {1} page(s)", oTgtDoc.Name, PgNum);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

    }
}
```

---

Finally, by drilling down the links you provided I think it could be useful to build a helper class and learn a bit about how Reflection works by exploiting `BuiltInDocumentProperties` object

```
using System;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using System.Reflection;

namespace WordHelpers
{
    class MyWordHelpers
    {   
        public static string GetBuiltInDocumentProperty(Word.Document oDoc, string propertyName)
        {
            object oDocBuiltInProps;

            oDocBuiltInProps = oDoc.BuiltInDocumentProperties;
            Type typeDocBuiltInProps = oDocBuiltInProps.GetType();

            //get the property
            object oDocAuthorProp = typeDocBuiltInProps.InvokeMember("Item",
                                       BindingFlags.Default |
                                       BindingFlags.GetProperty,
                                       null, oDocBuiltInProps,
                                       new object[] { propertyName }); // <-- here you exploit the passed property 

            //get the property type
            Type typeDocAuthorProp = oDocAuthorProp.GetType();

            // return the property value
            return typeDocAuthorProp.InvokeMember("Value",
                                       BindingFlags.Default |
                                       BindingFlags.GetProperty,
                                       null, oDocAuthorProp,
                                       new object[] { }).ToString(); ;
        }
    }

}
```

to be used as follows (from a console application)

```
static void RunWordExample()
{
    Word.Application oWord = new Word.Application(); //Create an instance of Microsoft Word

    //Create a new Document
    object oMissing = Missing.Value;
    Word.Document oTgtDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

    //make Word visible
    oWord.Visible = true;

    // get number of pages
    Console.WriteLine("doc {0} has {1} page(s)", oTgtDoc.Name, MyWordHelpers.GetBuiltInDocumentProperty(oTgtDoc,"Number of Pages"));
    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

Comment: Thanks. RE: **"you must use `var PgNum = oTgtDoc.BuiltInDocumentProperties(Word.WdBuiltInProperty.wdPropertyPages).Value.ToString();` and BTW `Word.Document oTgtDoc = new Word.Document();` won't return any new Word document (i.e. a 'real' new document in Word UI) but just a new word document object in your class."** Sure this is okay, in my code, just saved space.

Comment: This one should return the page number count. Does it? `var PgNum = oTgtDoc.BuiltInDocumentProperties(Word.WdBuiltInProperty.wdPropertyPages).Value.ToString();` I don't think so.

Comment: in my test it did. since I don't see your complete code maybe there's something missing and preventing it from functioning properly. see edited answer to show you how it worked for me

Comment: In fact, in the meantime I figured out how to exploit the Reflection. And I implemented that code, I even posted the code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37202933/6201755 BUT your solution with `var PgNum = oTgtDoc.BuiltInDocumentProperties(Word.WdBuiltInProperty.wdPropertyPages).Value.‌​ToString();` is the best! More direct and faster. Except I need to use `Int.Parse` to cast it to `int` so I can do a comparison.

Comment: glad to be of help. if my answer fulfilled your question please mark it as accepted. thank you

Comment: I am at a really tight spot. Both yours and Arina's are really good! You worked so much on this though but hers is the one I adopted as of now because of its succintness of code. I upvoted both of yours and hers and I am still testing. I think it is only fair if I accept the one that suits my application the best. But thank you very much for the lot of data and help in any case!

Comment: you're welcome. anyhow as far as "succinctness" is concerned you may agree that one line is more succinct then two... finally I added `To.String()` for the sake of having a string type to put in a `Console.Writeline()` statement (though not even strictly needed). should you need an `int` you just remove that `To.String()` and thus the `Int.Parse()`, too. you could even use `int PgNum = ... ` instead of `var PgNum = ...`. see edited answer

Comment: So you say *Value* is an int? I did not test this. Now the only question is which is faster. Though that is not really crucial, since the amount of iteration thriugh the loop is minimal as I have a good starting value for the table column.  Do you know which one is faster though to retrieve? The builtindocproperty or the statistics?

Comment: `int PgNum = oTgtDoc.BuiltInDocumentProperties(Word.WdBuiltInProperty.wdPropertyPages).Value;` returns an `int`.  `var PgNum = oTgtDoc.BuiltInDocumentProperties(Word.WdBuiltInProperty.wdPropertyPages).Value;` returns a `dynamic{int}`. I actually don't know which is faster since never had chance to test it, but that was not a issue of your original question which only asked for _"how to access this BuiltInDocumentProperties["Number of Pages"] from my C# code"_

Comment: Sure. See answer of Arina. I meant that being faster or not. But you are right, this was not in the scope of the OP.

Comment: well, your question was  _"how to access this BuiltInDocumentProperties["Number of Pages"] "_ and not _"how to get a document number of Pages"_ , so I concentrated on a `"BuiltInDocumentProperties"` document property solution.

Comment: Awesome. You even solved that riddle +1 Lol. Okay, you won! And will you upvote my very well composed question? ;-)

Comment: I'd agree this is a more complete answer to the question.
And I am indeed a he.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be from BuiltInDocumentProperties?

You could try this:

```
// get number of pages
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdStatistic stat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdStatistic.wdStatisticPages;
int pages = doc.ComputeStatistics(stat, Type.Missing);
```

Copied from this answer:
[How to get page number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749344/how-to-get-page-number)

[More info on Word statistics from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdstatistic.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: This one is also really good. In fact a simpler rendition: `PgNum = oTgtDoc.ComputeStatistics(Word.WdStatistic.wdStatisticPages, Type.Missing);` Since I already have a `using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;`  And this one does not event need to be cast. I wonder which one is actually faster, this and the other one above seem to be pretty fast. Would be interesting to time it. I believe I will choose your version, because of the simplicity of the code.